# ExtractField$Key doesn't work with MySqlCdcSource in Confluent Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm creating the following connector:

```
CREATE
SOURCE CONNECTOR IF NOT EXISTS `myconn` WITH (
    "name" = 'myconn',
    "connector.class" = 'MySqlCdcSource',
    "tasks.max" = 1,

    --Database config--------------------------

    "database.hostname" = '${dbHost}',
    "database.port"....

    --Kafka config------------------------------

    "kafka.api.key" = '${kafkaApiKey}',
    "kafka.auth.mode"...

    --Connector behavior------------------------

    "output.data.format" = 'AVRO',
    "output.key.format" = 'STRING',
    "key.converter" = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
    "key.converter.schemas.enable" = true,
    "tombstones.on.delete" = true,
    "null.handling.mode" = 'keep',
    "include.schema.changes" = false,
    "table.include.list" = 'sandbox\.(xxx|yyy)',
    "errors.tolerance" = 'none',
    "errors.log.enable" = true,
    "errors.log.include.messages" = true,

    --Topics configuration----------------------

    "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy" = 'compact',
    "topic.creation.default.min.insync.replicas"...

    --Predicates--------------------------------

    "predicates" = 'TopicDoestHaveIdField',
    "predicates.TopicDoestHaveIdField.type" = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches',
    "predicates.TopicDoestHaveIdField.pattern" = 'myconn.sandbox\.(zzz|ooo)$',

    --Transforms--------------------------------

    "transforms" = 'extractKey',

    "transforms.extractKey.type" = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key',
    "transforms.extractKey.field" = 'id',
    "transforms.extractKey.predicate" = 'TopicDoestHaveIdField',
    "transforms.extractKey.negate" = true
);
```

In local development I'm working with `io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector` and the transformation works correctly, the problem is when I make de creation in Confluent Cloud (using MySqlCdcSource). It gives me the following error:

```
The field configured for org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField transform does not exist in the key or value of Kafka records. Please verify the record's key or value has the configured field.
```

The problem is that it doesn't find the field Id, but when I make a test without the transformation, I see this key in the topic: `Struct(id=0000)`, so the field exists. I suppose it should be related with types or some configuration option is missed in my connector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related with a wrong usage of a predicate. Take a look at the following part:

```
--Predicates--------------------------------

"predicates" = 'TopicDoestHaveIdField',
"predicates.TopicDoestHaveIdField.type" = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches',
"predicates.TopicDoestHaveIdField.pattern" = 'myconn.sandbox\.(zzz|ooo)$',

--Transforms--------------------------------

"transforms" = 'extractKey',

"transforms.extractKey.type" = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key',
"transforms.extractKey.field" = 'id',
"transforms.extractKey.predicate" = 'TopicDoestHaveIdField',
"transforms.extractKey.negate" = true
```

As you can see `negate` is being used, so `extractKey` transforms includes all the tables that doesn't match with it. Despite that I was using `"table.include.list"`, some topics where included additionally and they didn't have `id` field.

In my case the confusion was motivated because of the message in log:

`The field configured for org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField transform does not exist in the key or value of Kafka records. Please verify the record's key or value has the configured field.`

(No information about the involved topic) I was supposing that the message was talking about any of the both allowed tables ('zzz' or 'ooo') but in the end it was another third topic included.